# SpEL：The performance of expression evaluation is not noticeably different, when use SpEL Compilation

Tags: java, spring, expression

I read the [SpEL](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.7.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions-spel-compilation) documentation, and learned that SpEL Compilation can improve performance. But I wrote a simple test case and the performance did not noticeably improve. **Why?**

Class define:

```java
public class PersonContainer {
    public List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>();
}

class Person {
    public Address address;
}

class Address {
    public double code;
}
```

Test Case:

```java
SpelParserConfiguration config = new SpelParserConfiguration(SpelCompilerMode.IMMEDIATE,
    this.getClass().getClassLoader());
ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser(config);
Expression expression = parser.parseExpression("personList[0].address.code < 0.2");

PersonContainer simple = new PersonContainer();
Address address1 = new Address();
address1.code = 0.1;
Person person = new Person();
person.address = address1;
simple.personList.add(person);

long begin = System.nanoTime();
for (int i = 0; i < 50000; i++) {
    expression.getValue(simple, Boolean.class);
}
long end = System.nanoTime();
System.out.println(end - begin);
```

The output use different SpelCompilerMode:

```
OFF：      256158300
IMMEDIATE: 262268500
MIXED:     276793400
```

Comment: Run your code under a profiler and see where the time is going.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure all the classes are `public`. There are various reasons why SpEL may decide that an expression cannot be compiled. class being used in the expression and not being public is one of them. You can enable debug log to see if the expression is actually being compiled, and trace through the spring compile code to look at the reason.

With Person and Address class changed to public, you can see the difference in the runtime.

```
OFF         :       505040500 ns
IMMEDIATE   :        13948300 ns
MIXED       :        24264200 ns
```